# Opening POP UP window by clicking hyperlink asp.net(C#)

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, popup

Guys I need to open a pop up window to play an audio file when my user clicks a hyperlink on a web page.

Till now I tried this

```
 <a   href='Conversation.aspx?<%#Eval("Connection") %>' onClick='<%# Eval("Connection","openWindow(""{0}"");") %>' >Access this conversation</a>
```

But this does not works.It seems I have not put the Onclick event properly.
Any ideas of how I can acheive this or what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Use `target="_blank"`

Comment: The return value from the onClick code is what determines whether the link's inherent clicked action is processed or not - returning false means that it isn't processed, but if you return true then the browser will proceed to process it after your function returns and go to the proper anchor

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this if you want a popup window

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:w= window.open('<%# String.Format("{0}", Eval("Connection")) %>','DownloadFile','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;" >Access this conversation</a>
```